# Nested API calls PHP

Tags: php, json

I make an API call which return a list of items. I use a foreach loop to iterate the JSON data:

```
 foreach($decoded_results['items'] as $item) {
      $image_link = $item['thumb'];
      $link_url = $item['url'];
      $subject = $item['title'];
 }
```

I need some additional information for each item and in order to get that I need to call another endpoint.

In my first response every item in the JSON object has a property with an `ID` that corresponds to a property with the same `ID` in the other JSON object, that I get as a response when I call the second endpoint. This ID is needed as a parameter in the query string for the second API call.

What would be the best approach to accomplish this? I've looked into `curl_multi` a little bit but not sure if this is suitable for the situation.

Comment: Do you have any say in building that API?
If so, you could build an endpoint accepting multiple ids and delivering the desired content for those id's.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be if your second API has an endpoint that accepts a list of IDs and can return all the information you need in one call, otherwise it is known as [the N+1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue) in database management, it is also the same here and is not an optimal solution.